# SQL INSERT using tables where the columns have different data types and getting error converting

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert

I have two tables and I would like to insert from one into the other. In my staging (source) table every column is defined as `nvarchar(300)` and this restriction cannot change.

In my destination table, the columns are of all different types. If I want to, for example, select from the source table (data type `nvarchar(300)`) and insert that column into a data type of `decimal(28, 16)`.

When this happens I get the following error:

> *Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.*

Even when I use a cast I get the error.

```
INSERT INTO Destination (
    Weighting
)
VALUES (
    CAST(src.Weighting AS decimal(28, 16))
)
```

Could `null` values be affecting this at all? Is there anything else to consider?

Comment: Are you sure it is a string that can be cast?  Test isnumeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all data in your staging table column can be implicitly converted to the target data type then you do not have to set up an explicit cast.

But if any one value cannot be converted implicitly (i.e. one cell contains a non-numeric or ill-formatted string value that is supposed to end up in a `decimal` type column) then the entire transaction will fail.

You can migrate the risk of a failing transaction by setting up the insert like this:

```
INSERT
  LiveTable (
    VarcharCol,
    DecimalCol,
    NonNullableCol
  )
SELECT
  NvarcharCol1,
  CASE ISNUMERIC(nvarcharCol2) = 0 THEN NvarcharColl2 END,
  ISNULL(NvarcharCol3, '')
FROM
  StagingTable
```

But clearly that means the risk of losing potentially relevant data or numeric precision.

You can read [which data types are implicitly convertible between each other](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) on the MSDN (scroll down to the matrix). For all other conversions you'll have to use `CAST` or `CONVERT`.

Answer (score 1):

This will search for non numeric strings

select src.Weighting from src  where isnumeric(src.Weighting) = 0

Comment: This was helpful - I ran it on all of the columns in my query. Turned out `Weighting` had values of `parent` in the column. Thanks.

Comment: Then in the insert add a where isnumeric(src.Weighting) = 1 for values that can be converted.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Destination (Weighting)
SELECT CAST(src.Weighting AS decimal(28, 16))
  FROM [Source] src
```

should work OK, provided your varchar values are in correct format.
If the error still occurs, please give an example of value being converted.

NULLs will successfully convert to NULLs.

Answer (score 0):

TSQL has [functions for casting or converting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) data to the type you want it to be.  If your data types in the source are strictly what you are trying to store them as in the destination table and with in the specifications of the destination table you won't have much trouble.

If you have a column of numbers and one of the is 'three' instead of '3' it gets complicated.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089125/varchar-to-decimal) is a question about converting a varchar to a decimal

An example: I can cast 123 as a varchar(20) then cast the varchar into a decimal with no problem when it is appropriate.

```
SELECT cast(cast('123' as varchar(20)) as decimal(8,2))
```

However if I try to convert a character it will give an error.

```
SELECT cast(cast('1a3' as varchar(20)) as decimal(8,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The null only be a problem if the target column does not allow nulls, I think the problem is that the format string that can not always be converted into a decimal, see if the decimal separator is a comma instead of a point.