# sum columns dynamically sql

Tags: sql, xml, dynamic-sql

I have multiple columns with some amount in a table and I want to show the total of all those amounts in the last Total column. I have a table in sql which looks somewhat like this,

```
A_Amt  B_Amt  C_Amt  D_Amt  E_Amt  F_Amt ... 
------------------------------------------------
 15     20     25     30     35    40
```

i have written a query as

```
declare @xmlResult xml=
(   
    select  * 
    from    Foo 
    for xml PATH
);

SELECT Nodes.node.value('sum(*[contains(local-name(.), "_Amt")])', 'decimal(15,2)') AS Total
  FROM
  @xmlResult.nodes('//row') as Nodes(node);
```

but the result I am getting has only one column total but i want all the columns in resultant table like A_amt etc..

Comment: if you are using sql server 2012 and above , why don't you try computed column feature.

Comment: @Prashant could u  explain in detail

Comment: This is not `MySQL`. Please tag the question correctly. Use only the tags that match the language and/or product it refers.

Comment: check this link ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Are you trying to have a column summation at the button or are you trying to get a row summation? Or do you want both?  In my answer, result1 does the row summation. Result2 is the column summation. Thanks to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you need, BUT ATTENTION! You should NOT do this. Aggregate rows should NEVER be fetched together with the "raw" data. This is - in most cases - something your UI should do (or a report...)

```
declare @table TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, a INT,b INT,c INT);
insert into @table VALUES(1,1,1),(2,3,4),(5,6,7);

    SELECT a,b,c
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.ID) AS inx
              ,a,b,c
        FROM @table AS t
        UNION SELECT 999999,SUM(a),SUM(b),SUM(c)
        FROM @table
    ) AS tbl
    ORDER BY tbl.inx
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Microsoft's system table is one way to achieve dynamic SQL and thus your goal. The code below is what you want or will at least get you started.

I wasn't sure what output you expected, so I included two outputs. Just use the one you want and discard the other one.  Given your question, it is probably result1. (Result1 or Result2)

!!You have to write the table name in the script at the place indicated prior to executing it!!

```
--DISCLAIMER
--It assume you use SQL SERVER 2012. (Probably work on 2005+ with little adjustment)
--It assume data is in a table, (Not a view for example)
--Changing SQL SERVER version may break the code as Microsoft could change "system views".
--I don't remember well, but EXEC may be limited to 4000 characters in dynamic query. (But there is a work around, just look around if you need it)
--So use at your own risk

DECLARE @objectIDTable              INT,
        @AllColumnAdditionStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
        @TableName                  NVARCHAR(250) = 'WriteYourTableNameHere',--!!!OVERWRITE THE TABLE NAME HERE
        @Query                      NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @AllSumStatement            NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT TOP 1    @objectIDTable              = [object_id],
                @AllColumnAdditionStatement = ''
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
AND name = @TableName

SELECT  @AllColumnAdditionStatement = @AllColumnAdditionStatement + 'CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 4), (CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(' + name + ') = 1 THEN ISNULL(' + name + ', ''0'') ELSE 0 END))' + ' + ',
        @AllSumStatement            = @AllSumStatement + name + 'Total = SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 4), (CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(' + name + ') = 1 THEN ISNULL(' + name + ', ''0'') ELSE 0 END))), ' + CHAR(10)
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = @objectIDTable
AND name LIKE '%_Amt' --!!!Here is a column filter/selector to sum only column ending with _Amt

SELECT  @AllColumnAdditionStatement = @AllColumnAdditionStatement + '0', --just too lazy to chop off last three char
        @AllSumStatement            = @AllSumStatement + 'Total_ = SUM(' + @AllColumnAdditionStatement + ')' + CHAR(10),
        @Query = 'SELECT *,
                        Total_ = ' + @AllColumnAdditionStatement +'
                 FROM ' + @TableName

PRINT (@Query)
/********************************************************************************************/
EXEC (@Query) --or use sp_execute if you prefer  
--Result1 : addition of all selected columns into total column with all column return as well

/********************************************************************************************/

SELECT @Query = 'SELECT ' + @AllSumStatement + '
                 FROM ' + @TableName

EXEC (@Query) --or use sp_execute if you prefer
--Result2 : Summation of all column individualy and summation of all of them into total column
/********************************************************************************************/
```

Comment: "The bellowing should ouput ..."   An apt word choice; most people will be bellowing when they see him using dynamic SQL to sum columns.

Comment: Error converting data type varchar to float shows up

Comment: Something as stupid as having a comma instead of a dot will crash the conversion. It is possible to handle non-numeric character, but code will start to look messy. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089125/varchar-to-decimal

Comment: @AXMIM "The bellowing" is a synonym for "The yelling", "the hollering", "the shouting".  You should have written "The below". "should output" was perfectly good English however. I apologize for making fun of your use of language.  In addition, yes, I believe doing calculations like this in SQL are a bad idea.

Comment: @Ross Thanks a lot for correcting me. :D  and yes I agree with you.

Comment: @Anshul I edited my answer to handle null value and added protection again non-numeric value.

Comment: Also be aware that SQL need dot for decimal separator. Commas doesn't work. This isn't handled in my solution. Would need to add more stuff to it to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for, try this (replace spt_values with your table) :

```
 USE MASTER
 GO 

 declare @lsql nvarchar(max)
 declare @lsql2 nvarchar(max)
 declare @yourTable nvarchar(255) = 'spt_values'

 Select @lsql = isnull(@lsql+'+','') + 'Case When ISNUMERIC('+name+') = 1 Then '+name+' else 0 end' from sys.Columns where Object_id = Object_id(@yourTable)

 Print @lsql


 SET @lsql2 = 'Select *, '+@lsql+' as Total_allcolumns From '+@yourTable+''

 Exec(@lsql2)
```