# Order by Nvarchar column containing decimal value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following table and data in sql server database. I am trying to fetch data order by `[Version]`  column. I want result arranged  as follows:

[image]

How can i achieve this?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DocumentLog](
[DocID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Version] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO DocumentLog (DocID,[version])values('doc0001','0.1');
INSERT INTO DocumentLog (DocID,[version])values('doc0001','0.5');
INSERT INTO DocumentLog (DocID,[version])values('doc0001','0.3');
INSERT INTO DocumentLog (DocID,[version])values('doc0001','0.4');
INSERT INTO DocumentLog (DocID,[version])values('doc0001','0.2');
INSERT INTO DocumentLog (DocID,[version])values('doc0001','0.6');
INSERT INTO DocumentLog (DocID,[version])values('doc0001','0.7');
INSERT INTO DocumentLog (DocID,[version])values('doc0001','0.9');
INSERT INTO DocumentLog (DocID,[version])values('doc0001','0.8');
INSERT INTO DocumentLog (DocID,[version])values('doc0001','0.10');
INSERT INTO DocumentLog (DocID,[version])values('doc0001','0.11');
INSERT INTO DocumentLog (DocID,[version])values('doc0001','0.12');
INSERT INTO DocumentLog (DocID,[version])values('doc0001','0.13');
INSERT INTO DocumentLog (DocID,[version])values('doc0001','0.14');
INSERT INTO DocumentLog (DocID,[version])values('doc0001','0.15');
INSERT INTO DocumentLog (DocID,[version])values('doc0001','0.16');
INSERT INTO DocumentLog (DocID,[version])values('doc0001','0.17');
INSERT INTO DocumentLog (DocID,[version])values('doc0001','0.18');
INSERT INTO DocumentLog (DocID,[version])values('doc0001','1.0');
INSERT INTO DocumentLog (DocID,[version])values('doc0001','1.1');
INSERT INTO DocumentLog (DocID,[version])values('doc0001','1.10');
INSERT INTO DocumentLog (DocID,[version])values('doc0001','2.0');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VARCHAR to DECIMAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089125/varchar-to-decimal)

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You are struggling here because you did not properly normalize your data. You are violating 1NF by sticking two pieces of information into a single column. If you had those two pieces of information in their own column this would be simple and you wouldn't have posted a question. When you design tables incorrectly you run into this sort of challenge.

Comment: yes you are right but it is existing table..not designed by me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real issue here is your table structure. You should have two columns (or four in software versioning models) to hold version information. Since you don't have that you have to deal with this in a totally convoluted way. Since your data appears to be consistent you could leverage [PARSENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for this.

```
select * 
from DocumentLog
order by convert(int, PARSENAME(Version, 2))
    , convert(int, PARSENAME(Version, 1))
```

Comment: `PARSENAME` strikes again! I think this function is used more for this kind of stuff versus it's demo'd reason of parsing the server.schema.db

Comment: @scsimon LOL you are probably right. I have used it for its "intended" purpose maybe once or twice but lots of times for all sorts of various parsing of stuff. :D

Comment: @UjwalKhairnar Does that work for you? `PARSENAME` only works with sql server 2012+ according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)...

Comment: @MatSnow PARSENAME has been around a LONG time. The documentation from MS is one of the most frustrating things lately. They remove versions that are no longer in mainstream support. It has been around since at least sql 2000. Can't remember if it that was new at the time or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT
    *,
    TRY_CAST(LEFT([version], CHARINDEX('.', [version])-1) AS int) MainVer,
    TRY_CAST(RIGHT([version], LEN([version]) - CHARINDEX('.', [version])) AS int) AS SubVer
FROM DocumentLog
ORDER BY MainVer, SubVer;
```

For SQL Server before 2012 replace `TRY_CAST` with `CAST`.

Comment: TRY_CAST is not supporting in SQL Server 2008 R2 :(

Comment: You can change it to `CAST` but you'll get an error if the version column contains `A.B` for example.

Comment: it wont be. it will be always numeric