# How to return a dynamic decimal data type in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to add two parameters to the function below and return the result as DECIMAL(@p1, @p2) but I'm getting a syntax error for it - how can I do that?

```
/*
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT [dbo].fn_ConvertTextToDecimal_19_4('', 0) -- NULL
SELECT [dbo].fn_ConvertTextToDecimal_19_4('', 1) -- 0.0000
SELECT [dbo].fn_ConvertTextToDecimal_19_4('100', 1) -- 100.0000
SELECT [dbo].fn_ConvertTextToDecimal_19_4('1234567890123456.1234', 0) -- NULL
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ConvertTextToDecimal_19_4]
(
    @Decimal_Number VARCHAR(50),
    @Fail_As_Zero BIT
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(19, 4)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 
    (
        CASE WHEN 
                TRY_CAST(@Decimal_Number AS DECIMAL(19, 4)) IS NULL
            THEN
                CASE WHEN (@Fail_As_Zero = 1)
                    THEN 0
                    ELSE NULL
                END
            ELSE 
                TRY_CAST(@Decimal_Number AS DECIMAL(19, 4))
        END
    )
END
```

**UPDATE**
- after I found that this needs to be compatible with SQL Server 2008 I added this baby:

```
/*
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PURPOSE     : Convert a string into decimal(19,4)
    (this is a workaround for SQL server 2008 where TRY_CAST cannot be used)
    based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089125/varchar-to-decimal
    otherwise it can be casted as follows:
    ISNULL(TRY_CAST([column_name] AS DECIMAL(19, 4)), 0) AS [Test_1]
    ISNULL(TRY_CAST([column_name] AS DECIMAL(19, 4)), NULL) AS [Test_2]
NOTE        : for different precision, change the constants in the code (19, 4, 16)
USAGE       :
SELECT [dbo].fn_ConvertTextToDecimal_19_4('', 0) -- NULL
SELECT [dbo].fn_ConvertTextToDecimal_19_4('', 1) -- 0.0000
SELECT [dbo].fn_ConvertTextToDecimal_19_4('100', 1) -- 100.0000
SELECT [dbo].fn_ConvertTextToDecimal_19_4('-123456789012345.1234', 0) -- -123456789012345.1234
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ConvertTextToDecimal_19_4]
(
    @Decimal_Number VARCHAR(50),
    @Fail_As_Zero BIT
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(19, 4)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 
    (
        CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(@Decimal_Number) = 1
                AND CHARINDEX('.', @Decimal_Number) = 0
                AND LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Decimal_Number, '-', ''), '+', '')) < 16
                THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(19, 4), @Decimal_Number)
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(@Decimal_Number) = 1
                AND (CHARINDEX('.', @Decimal_Number) !=0
                    AND CHARINDEX('.', REPLACE(REPLACE(@Decimal_Number, '-', ''), '+', '')) <= 16)
                THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(19, 4), 
                    CASE WHEN LEN(@Decimal_Number) - LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Decimal_Number, '0', ''), '1', ''), '2', ''), '3', ''), '4', ''), '5', ''), '6', ''), '7', ''), '8', ''), '9', '')) <= 19 
                        THEN @Decimal_Number 
                        ELSE SUBSTRING(@Decimal_Number, 1, 19 + LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Decimal_Number, '0', ''), '1', ''), '2', ''), '3', ''), '4', ''), '5', ''), '6', ''), '7', ''), '8', ''), '9', ''))) 
                    END
                )
            ELSE
                CASE WHEN (@Fail_As_Zero = 1)
                    THEN 0
                    ELSE NULL
                END
            END
    )
END
GO
```

Magic numbers are: (38, 10, 29) (19, 6, 14) (19, 4, 16)

Comment: I have to ask, why would you use a function for this?  Also, the case statement isn't needed... the result would be the same just using TRY_CAST, which leads me back to my original question, why not use TRY_CAST in the code?

Comment: This who function could be replaced with the plain `TRY_CAST`, why are you doing this?

Comment: You cannot construct a decimal with a dynamic scale and precision *explicitly* -- variables are not allowed in type expressions, as T-SQL is (almost) fully statically typed. You can do so *implicitly*, by properly manipulating your expressions (and a temp table, I think), but... it's not pretty. Do you have a real use case for this and if so, what is it? You'll probably either need dynamic SQL, or a complete rethink where you do more in client code.

Comment: I just I don't want to repeat this over and over again, so I was trying to create a dynamic function for that - so I can do a 1 line cast...

Comment: Unfortunately, the usual outcome of "I want to do this particular thing in T-SQL to save on typing" is "that's too bad, because making you type a lot is T-SQL's way of saying 'I love you'". This case is probably no different. (Although, really, `TRY_CAST(.. AS DECIMAL(.., ..))` is not *too* burdensome, surely?)

Comment: I have to agree with the others here. Using a function seems like a complete waste of effort. It would be less typing to use TRY_CAST in your code then typing that function name. You will be blessed with flexibility and performance too. You really don't need the case expression as it is also redundant. Just return the TRY_CAST. If it fails it will be NULL, no need to check if it is NULL and then return NULL.

Comment: Jeroen Mostert - that would work but I was planning to add more to this function, for example, another parameter that will determine if to return 0 or NULL in case it fails...

Comment: I can only encourage you to put such thoughts out of your head. Even when you get this to work, using scalar-valued functions in T-SQL comes with a terrible and well-documented performance burden. While you can work around this by using inline table-valued functions, you then lose most of the benefits of readability such a function would have. For things that contain no essential business logic that should not be repeated and are just there to save on keystrokes, just write it all out (you can use CTEs to organize and deduplicate expressions). The optimizer will like you better.

Comment: Good point, I don't want to lose on performance, I wonder if I can do that kind of thing in a SP instead

Comment: Again a function is complete overkill. If you want it to return 0 when the parse fails just put it inside ISNULL(TRY_CAST(YourValue as Decimal(19, 4)), 0). You are way over thinking this.

Comment: Sean Lange - yes, I agree, I'm just surprised that the return type can not be dynamic

Comment: If you want to get *really* technical, T-SQL does have a "dynamic" return type in the form of `SQL_VARIANT`. But its use is very limited, because you can't do much of anything with it unless you cast it first, which means it's useless for this application. I've walked this road myself; I'm afraid there's only disappointment at the end. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this (in a reasonable way) in SQL Server.  The problem?  You cannot pass precision and length to `decimal` as parameters.

The "obvious" solution is to use dynamic SQL.  Alas, that doesn't work, because functions cannot invoke dynamic SQL (well there is a way, but it involves so much overhead that you might as well laugh at the work-around).

Another solution would be a really fun `case` expression:

```
(case when @p = 1 and @s = 1 then try_cast(@input as decimal(1, 1))
      . . .
```

There would only be about 38 * 38 / 2 = 722 conditions (precision cannot be smaller than scale).

I'm not sure why you actually care about the precision and scale of a numeric value.  Why not just use [`str()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or `format()` and convert to a string with the representation you want?

EDIT:

After writing all of this, I realize that the function has to return a single type.  You can't parameterize the scale and precision on the return value, so SQL Server simply doesn't support what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks, also an interesting idea, since it's just a switch case it might actually be very fast (I'm almost tempted to try it)

Comment: Please don't @Yovav, and understand Gordon is almost certainly not advocating for you to replicate and complicate the TRY_CAST function

Comment: The proposed solution will not actually work, because the type of a `CASE` expression can still only be one single type, likewise the return type of a function. I can't be bothered to work out what the resulting type of the `CASE` would be using the rather arcane rules for conversion, but it's rarely going to be what you need... (If you follow this up with some other expression so the result does not ultimately depend on the `DECIMAL`, it can work -- but since you then have to copy *that*, that's not going to save on typing much.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert . . . That is a really good point.  The situation is even worse.  Forget the `case` expression, the *function* can't return variable scales and precisions.